What is preventing my screen from dimming or sleeping?
I'm running Noble 24.04.1 LTS on a Thinkpad X1.
For the last few weeks, I've noticed that my laptop does not reliably lock, dim or suspend when it isn't in use.
The power settings suggest that it should dim when it's inactive, blank after 3 minutes, and suspend after 15. For the last few weeks I've noticed that it doesn't at all. I'll walk away from my desk and if I didn't use ctrl l to lock the screen, everything is still just open when I return. I have (obviously?) restarted it in that time.

What should I look at to figure out what is preventing my screen from dimming and suspending?
Reading through How do I tell what's preventing sleep on Ubuntu? My box won't sleep automatically!
When I run gsettings list-recursively  | grep plugins.power I'm getting these settings, which seem correct:
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power ambient-enabled true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-brightness 30
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action 'interactive'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-saver-profile-on-low-battery true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 900
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 900
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'suspend'

I tried running systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block and got:
WHO           UID  USER   PID    COMM            WHAT                                                     WHY                       MODE 
amanda        1001 amanda 469317 gsd-media-keys  handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key GNOME handling keypresses block
amanda        1001 amanda 469014 gnome-session-b shutdown                                                 user session inhibited    block

2 inhibitors listed.

I'm not sure what to make of the results. gsd-media-keys isn't something I'm familiar with.
Running journalctl -u systemd-logind.service is about what I expect. Last night I was working on the couch, so it suspended when I closed the lid. This morning I had to open the lid to wake it at my desk with my external monitor and keyboard. Then I closed the lid because it was awake. And then at noonish I migrated from my desk to the couch and opened the lid. Since then I went away for ten minutes and it definitely did not dim, but there's no indication of what might have prevented it.
Nov 26 08:07:50 omori systemd-logind[1337]: Lid opened.
Nov 26 08:07:50 omori systemd-logind[1337]: Operation 'suspend' finished.
Nov 26 08:07:53 omori systemd-logind[1337]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event16 (KINESIS FREESTYLE KB800 KB800 Kinesis Freestyle)
Nov 26 08:07:53 omori systemd-logind[1337]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event15 (KINESIS FREESTYLE KB800 KB800 Kinesis Freestyle)
Nov 26 08:08:07 omori systemd-logind[1337]: Lid closed.
Nov 26 12:00:25 omori systemd-logind[1337]: Lid opened.

Is gsd-media-keys somehow responsible for this? I'd like my laptop to actually suspend and not stay on all night if I don't shut down.
